# Cannot get += to work properly between functions in python

Tags: python, function

So my task is simple: I am to make two functions,

one which takes input from a user as a list of integers. (User enters how many entries, then begins entering them individually)

second function reads that list and returns how many times a chosen value was found in that list.

For some reason when combining these functions, the count does not stay at 0 and count whenever x is seen in the list; it just jumps to whatever the initial entry count was.

code is as follows:

```
def get_int_list_from_user():

    list1 = []
    numNums = int(input("Enter number count: "))

    for x in range(numNums):
        nextval = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
        list1.append(nextval)
    return list1

def count_target_in_list(int_list):

    target_val = int(input("Enter target value: "))
    count = 0
    for target_val in int_list:
        count += 1
    
    print("Target counted ", count, "time(s)")

    return count
```

Over here is where I've tried different ways of calling the functions, but each time just ends up with the same result.

```
list1 = my_functions.get_int_list_from_user()
count = my_functions.count_target_in_list(int_list=list1)
```

I also tried this:

```
my_functions.count_target_in_list(int_list=my_functions.get_int_list_from_user())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement does not do what you think it does:

```
for target_val in int_list:
```

That essentially erases the original value passed into the function, and instead runs through the whole list, one element at a time.  So, `count` will always be equal to the length of the list.  You wanted:

```
for val in int_list:
    if val == target_val:
        count += 1
```

Comment: @Grelm you can also use this `count = int_list.count(target_val)` to count the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_target_in_list(int_list):

    target_val = int(input("Enter target value: "))
    count = 0
    for target_val in int_list:
        count += 1
    
    print("Target counted ", count, "time(s)")

    return count
```

instead, using this logic, you need to compare the loop values with the target value. in the code above the target value will be overridden by the iteration of the loop.

```
def count_target_in_list(int_list):

    target_val = int(input("Enter target value: "))
    count = 0
    for value in int_list:
        if target_val == value :
            count += 1
    
    print("Target counted ", count, "time(s)")

    return count
```